# How to use airodump command in system(gnome-terminal ) (ruby)?

Tags: terminal, ruby

I used this instruction in my ruby script:

```
system "gnome-terminal -e bash -c sudo timeout 20 airodump-ng wlp2s0mon -w mt --output-format csv --write-interval 20"
```

With this instruction I would like to open a second terminal to run the `airodump` command and then continue working in the first terminal.

The above command is not working, how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

this opens up a new tab in terminal called airodump with airodump-ng launched with the provided command

```
#!/bin/bash        
    gnome-terminal --tab --title="airodump" -- sudo airodump-ng wlan0mon

# or anny other command you want to run with airodump-ng

# airodump-ng -c Channel --bssid -w filename [your wifi card in monitor mode mon ]
```